# Dropdown on click of image

Tags: javascript

I want to open a dropdown on click of a image and also display a alert message that which of the dropdown option is being clicked .

My html code is :

```
<div class="account_notification">
<a href="#">
<div class="notify_notification">click</div><!-- notify_notification close --></a>
</div><!-- account_notification close -->
<select class="select1" size="5" style="display:none">        
    <option name="test" value="" class="first">Select</option>       
    <option name="test" value="" class="">NOTIFICATION1</option>       
    <option name="test" value="" class="">NOTIFICATION2</option> 
</select>
```

What will be javascript code to do so ?

Though i found a jquery on inernet for dropdown display but that also without showing which option is selected and also i know very little about jquery .So i want code in javascript.Please help

Jquery i found is as follow :

```
$('.notify_notification').click(function() {
    $('.select1').toggle();
});
```

I got the code from answers but the problem here is suppose before click if the bar is like this:

http://postimg.org/image/n04ggm7ux/

After clicking the image the bar become :

http://postimg.org/image/4h344hl7t/

How to get it down instead of being displayed along side ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to **open** the dropdown, not just to unhide the select element... Well, you're in trouble, because there is no generic or simple solution for that. Consider building your custom drop-down, trying another elements (like radio buttons) or using [Shadow DOM](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/).
2. To show the selected option, use something like this:

   ```
   alert($('.select1 option:selected').text()); //show text of selected option
   alert($('.select1').val()); //show selected value
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You actual code is showing/hide the select; if you want to open the select programmatically is not possible even if you trigger a click the drop down list won't open like if the user clicked on it. An alternative is to use a custom select display plugin (like `chosen`).

To display the select value on option click use the `change` event:

```
$('.select1').change(function(){ 
    alert($(this).val());
    alert($(this).find('option:selected').text())
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/YdJzP/

Answer (score 0):

If you want only JavaScript solution.

You can toggle your combo with this:

```
function toggle(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("myselect");
    if(elem.style.display == "none")
        elem.style.display = "block";
    else
        elem.style.display = "none";
};
```

And after adding `onchange="selectHandler(this)"` to your select on html, you can get selected value with:

```
function selectHandler(x) {
    if(x.value!="")
        alert("Selected: "+x.value); 

    toggle();
}
```

Here is a only example: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cemozer/Fx8hf/)**

Comment: Your code was undoubtdly helpful.But i am facing a problem in it,I edited it in my post.Please help to resolve it

Comment: You must use css for this, wrap every menu button that has a dropdown in a menu-item div and adjust your dropdown according to that button as you want. Check this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cemozer/Fx8hf/3/ Adjust top and left properties as you wish.